# Session is always null in action filter in asp.net core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to set a value in session and then want to retrieve it in action filter, have tried accessing through actionContext but still getting null session value, can't figure out where i am doing wrong. In my Authenticate Controller i am setting the session value after user credentials are verified.

```
public class AuthController : Controller {

 private IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor { get; }

 public AuthController (IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
    {
        httpContextAccessor = contextAccessor;
    }

private async Task<IActionResult> Login(signIn objDto){

          // Some Authenticate Code and token generation

          var claims = new[]
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier,user.Id.ToString()),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name,user.Username)
            };

            var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config.GetSection("Jwt:TokenSecretKey").Value));
            var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature);

            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
                SigningCredentials = creds
            };
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor));

          httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.SetString("token",token);

          //return Ok result with token
       }
}
```

but can't access it in onActionExecuting method in any next call.

```
public class WebAPIActionFilterHelper : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor { get; }

    public WebAPIActionFilterHelper(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
    {
        httpContextAccessor = contextAccessor;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext actionContext)
    {
   
        if (actionContext.Controller.GetType().Name == "AuthController")
            return;
          // Always return null session
        var token = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("token");
        if (token == null){
        actionContext.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();}

        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
    }
}
```

Following is my Startup class

```
public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(x => x.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddControllers(x => x.Filters.Add(typeof(WebAPIActionFilterHelper))).
                AddJsonOptions(o =>
              {
                  o.JsonSerializerOptions.MaxDepth = 999999999;
              });

            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
            services.AddCors();

            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            services.AddScoped<IAuthRepository, AuthRepository>();
            services.AddAuthorization();
            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(opt =>
                {
                    opt.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration.GetSection("Jwt:TokenSecretKey").Value)),
                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidateAudience = true,
                        ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                        ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                    };
                });
            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
            services.AddSession(opt =>
            {
                opt.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            
            app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseSession();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please review [MCVE] guidance. The code for  "i am setting the session value" is totally missing at least from the post (and possibly from your actual program).

Comment: It could work well in my project.How did you set the session?And be sure use the postman only or use other tool only.For example,do not alternate use postman and broswer to send request.

Comment: @Rena i have updated the question. I am actually sending request from my angular application.

Comment: Hi @ZafeerUlHaq,Did you debug the code and set breakpoint in the action filter to check the session is null?Please try to remove the `UnauthorizedResult` in action filter and check the result when you pass token. Because if your token does not valid,the result would also be 401 unauthorized.Did you mind sharing how do you send request by using angular and how do you generate the jwt token?

Comment: @Rena i did debug the code and quick watch the session value it is still null. However the `UnauthorizeResult` is only for controllers other than AuthController. I am just trying to work on Idle timeout , that is why i am storing the token in session and validate if it is still in the session. However i have updated the question with JWT token generation code. In angular i am just sending a simple post request.